# Connecting Xamarin.Android with SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Android application and I need it to connect to remote sql server database. I tried to use ADO.NET but it gives me error for SSL Certificate, and I tried to resolve it but not fruitful. 
Please help me with integrating Web Api or WCF Service.
Thanks.

Comment: You have not included any code, given us any specific error messages or exceptions, or explained what you've tried to do to resolve the problems on your own.  How are we supposed to help you when you haven't provided ANY useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect directly to a external database in xamarin, you need a layer between your app and database.That layer is called webservice.

I will help you do that.

1.Firstly create a database on 000webhost.com

2.Add a .php or .java file to connect and insert/select data from database in 000webhost file manager.

3.Access that .php file from your  application with the help of httpclient class.

For example, if you have to insert name,email,phone number and password in database just call your .php file and pass your parameters as POST or GET.

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
                        string ss = "https://YOUR 000WEBHOST WEBSITE ADDRESS/database.php";
                        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Name", name.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Email",email.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Mobile", mobile.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Password",password.Text)
                        });
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync(ss, formContent);
                        var responsedone = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```